# Check if a user is present in the database for a parameter other than ID

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I created 3 functions: `findOne`, `create` and `update`. Respectively the methods are `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`.
I changed my API path, it used to be `/api/users/:id`, now it's `/api/users/:sub`.

**routes.js**:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  const router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new User
  router.post("/", users.create);

  // Retrieve a single User with sub
  router.get("/:sub", users.findOne);

  // Update a User with sub
  router.put("/:sub", users.update);

  // Delete a User with sub
  router.delete("/:sub", users.delete);


  app.use('/api/users', router);
};
```

**controller.js**:

```
// Save User in the database
  User.create(user)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Users."
      });
    });
};


  // Find a single User with an id and sub
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  const sub = req.params.sub;
  

  User.findOne({sub})
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Error retrieving User with id=" +sub 
    });
  });
};

// Update a User by the sub in the request
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const sub = req.params.sub;

  User.update(req.body, {
    where: { sub }
  })
    .then(num => {
      if (sub) {
        res.send({
          message: "User was updated successfully."
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          message: `Cannot update User with sub=. Maybe User was not found or req.body is empty!`
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error updating User with sub=" 
      });
    });
};
```

What I wanted to do was: check if the `user_id` provided by the authentication provider was present in my database. 
If yes, update user data with that `user_id`.

If not, create a new user record

This is the **front-end** part involved:

```
//INFO SAVE AND UPDATE CONDITION
    const userExist =  InfoDataService.get(data.sub)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('find', response.data);
      return true;
    });
      
    

   if ( userExist ) {
    InfoDataService.create(data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('create', response.data);
        setInfo({
          id: response.data.id,
          sub: response.data.sub,
          email: response.data.email,
          firstname: response.data.firstname,
          lastname: response.data.lastname,
        });
      })
      
  } else {
    InfoDataService.update(sub, data)
      .then((response) => {
                
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }
  };
```

I thought `userInDatabase` could only give `true` or `false`, so I used it as an argument in the `if` statement. It does not work and just updates.
If you need any other information, please ask, I have just started and I hope I have given the necessary info.

**EDIT**
Through `findOne` I can find the entire object in my database, but I thought that putting the function as an `if` condition could give me `true` if it found the object with its `sub`; `false` if he found nothing.

This is not the case, in fact in the code I just updated, although `findOne` works correctly, it continues to execute always and only create.

Comment: Where did const id = req.params.id; comes from? There is no 'id' definition in your route's params.
Sequelize findOne has different arguments to findByPk. >> findOne({where:{...}})

Comment: I made a mistake editing the question, thanks.

Comment: When a user does not exist, it does not return error, but return `null` without any error. So you need to check the response, if it is `null` or nor after calling InfoDataService.get()